# How can I apply SHAP on a 3D dataset and LSTM model?

Tags: python, lstm, shap, mlops, causalml

I trained an LSTM model on a 3D dataset and now I’m trying to apply SHAP on the model and the dataset to obtain more advanced insights.
I made a lot of tests with all SHAP features but it seems no one support LSTM with 3D datasets. Is there a way to apply SHAP to this kind of model and dataset?

The 3D dataset has the following axis: [instance, timestep, feature] and the LSTM is built to address a multivariate problem.

Comment: the question needs sufficient code for a minimal reproducible example:
https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: Please [reprex]